# How can we know that |N is really the intersection of inductive sets?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

e := element of ;    fa := for all ; : := is valid ; P(X) := Powerset of X

An inductive set M is a subset of |R with the properties that

i)  1 e M
ii) fa x e M : x+1 e M

As the intersection |N must have all elements that the other subsets have. Because of the recursive Definition we know that

fa M e {x e P(|R) such that x is inductive} : 1 e M => 1+1 e M => ....

But I don't understand why there can be no inductive set Z which is also a real subset of |N, with other words why is |N the smallest inductive set? How can you formally proof that?

Answer (score 1):

This is where **proof by induction** comes in! Proof by induction is the application of the **induction axiom**, which states: $$\mbox{$P(0)$ and ($P(n)\rightarrow P(n+1)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$)$\implies$ $P(n)$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$}$$ for every property $P$.

Suppose $Z\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is any inductive set, and consider the property $P(x)$ = "$x$ is an element of $Z$."

- Clearly we have $P(0)$ and $P(x)\rightarrow P(x+1)$ for all $x$; this is just because $Z$ is inductive.
- But this means $\mathbb{N}\subseteq Z$: if $P(0)$ holds, and $P(n)\rightarrow P(n+1)$ for ever natural number $n$, then - by **the induction axiom** - $P(n)$ holds for every natural number $n$.

---

This may feel a bit unsatisfying: where does the assumption that $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies the induction axiom come from? Well, *nothing gets proved in a vacuum*: we need to start with some axioms about $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ in order to be able to conclude anything, and the induction axiom - or one of its many variants - is a crucial assumption.

In fact, the induction axiom is **equivalent to** $\mathbb{N}$ being the smallest inductive set! This may feel a bit more slippery at first, but it's really no more complicated mathematically:

- Suppose we have a property $P$ such that $P(0)$ holds and, for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $P(n)\rightarrow P(n+1)$; we want to show that $P(n)$ holds in fact for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, from the assumption that $\mathbb{N}$ is in fact the smallest inductive set.
- To do this, let $Z=\{n\in\mathbb{N}: P(n)\}$. By assumption on $P$, we know that $Z$ is an inductive set; since we're assuming that $\mathbb{N}$ is the intersection of all inductive sets, this means $\mathbb{N}\subseteq Z$.
- But that means that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $P(n)$ holds.
- So **we've just proved the induction axiom from the hypothesis "$\mathbb{N}$ is the smallest inductive set!"**

This sort of examination of the relationship between *axiom* and *theorem* occurs throughout mathematics. Much of [**abstract algebra**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_algebra) consists of understanding precisely which basic algebraic properties of the reals/naturals/etc. are necessary to get particular complicated behavior (in the interest of showing that these behaviors hold in more general situations), and it is a fundamental aspect of [**mathematical logic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_logic) *(especially [reverse mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics), which is worth mentioning if only for the really cool name)*.

Comment: Á = induction Axiom B = |N is the smallest inductive set.

Comment: You showed A->B and B->A

Comment: If there would exist a subset of |N like V which is also inductive then V c |N by assumption and |N c V with the Axiom so V = |N.

Comment: But what if there is an identity like 2^n > n^2 which only works n >= 5. Wouldn't the subset U of |N,  U = {5,6,..} also be inductive?

Comment: How is the induction Axiom applied in this case? I have already heard about variations of the induction. Does that mean that there are Statements which behave equivalent to the induction Axiom?

Comment: @RM777 Reread the definition carefully. Inductive sets are required to contain $1$, so $\{5,6,...\}$ is **not** inductive.